# Special indexing of two 1D numpy / torch arrays to produce another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, torch

Looking for an efficient (vectorized) way in Numpy or PyTorch to achieve the array `z` when given input arrays `x` and `y`:

1D array `x` contains a list of increasing ID's, each of which repeats 1 or more times (not necessarily repeating for the same number of times for each ID). For example, `[0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2]`

1D array `y` of 0's and 1's. There is *at least* one element equal to "1" for each unique ID in `x`. For example, `[1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]`.

1D output array `z` which is equal to `y`, but keeping only the first occurrence of "1" in `y` per ID in `x`. The remaining elements of `y` for that ID should be set to "0". So in the example, the result would be `[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]`

```
x: [0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2]
y: [1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
z: [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
```

I feel like there's a quick way to do this in Numpy or PyTorch, but I couldn't figure it out.

**Edit**: Here's the "slow" version using a while-loop

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
z = y.copy()
n = z.shape[0]
i = 0
while i < n:
    if y[i] == 1:
        current_id = x[i]
        i += 1
        while i < n and x[i] == current_id:
            z[i] = 0
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Let's start with the slow, but easy way to do this!

Comment: Updated question to include a basic algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.unique`:

```
unq, ind = np.unique(np.stack((x, y)), axis=1, return_index=True)
```

`ind` now contains the first occurrence of each unique combination of elements. You just need to remove the ones where `y` is zero:

```
keep = unq[1, :] != 0
ind = ind[keep]
```

Now you can make `z` directly:

```
z = np.zeros_like(y)
z[ind] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in a vectorized way, you could do this:

```
x = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])         
y = torch.tensor([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])         
                                                      
unique_vals = x.unique_consecutive().unsqueeze(1)     
masked_x = x.masked_fill(y != 1, unique_vals[-1][0]+1)
indices = (unique_vals == masked_x).int().argmax(1)   
res = torch.zeros_like(y).index_fill(0, indices, 1)   
print(res)
```

But I'm not convinced it'll be faster than the naive version.